# How to find the closest matching string pairs in 2D array

Tags: python, algorithm

Hello I have a 2D array filled with the fuzzy matching score of row and columns. Say for a very simple example

```
----------------------------------------
|     -      |   fst_name  | last_name |
----------------------------------------
| First Name |   89        |   72      |
----------------------------------------
| Last Name  |   82        |   95      |
----------------------------------------
```

I want to find out the pairs where `(i,j)` is maximum but we have to sure that one `i` can be paired with one `j` only. Here i and j are the index for row and column.
How can I do that in python. For fuzzy I am using levenshtein distance. I tried to implement backtracking but it is very slow for my use case.

Comment: What does `(i, j)` is maximum mean? Given the table above, what index pairs do you want?

Comment: do you just want to find one Largest SUM pair all All pairs sum is largest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the coding yourself but this might get you started:

1. transform the 2D array to a flat list `L` with tuples `(i, j, distance)`
2. Sort the list `L` based on `distance`
3. Pick the largest elements from the sorted list and do your comparison.

Comment: Solves my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to find a library that uses the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to solve the assignment problem on the Levenshtein distances. There's an implementation in [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html), as well as the [Python package `munkres`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/munkres/), which I know nothing about.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I enjoyed learning Hungarian Algorithm.